# How do I format the Custom Field DateTime?

Tags: custom-field-types, datepicker, date-time

I want to create a date input box. When you select a date, it puts it in the format dd/mm/yyyy using the following Custom Field.

```
  <Field ID="{3a521b04-fca1-4707-9134-fa4acd1456d8}" Name="RegistrationDate"
       DisplayName="Registration Date"
       Type="DateTime"
       Format="DateTime"
       Hidden="FALSE"
       Required="TRUE"/>
```

I want the format to be for example: "Tuesday 6, 2011"
Is there a way I can do it directly from here or do i have to use javascript on the client side.

Answer (score 2):

There are just two types of date format available in fields `DateTime` and `DateOnly`.

However there is a little workaround available:
Create additional calculated field and in formula use:

```
=TEXT([Registration Date],"dddd d, yyyy")
```

This new will render your Registration Date field as you required.

Answer (score 0):

There's a Data View format functionality that can be seen here:
[SharePoint Data View Web Part Extension Functions in the ddwrt Namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa505323.aspx#officesharepointddwrt_formatdate)